# Is there an event for after a shipping method is saved in admin?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, shipping, event-observer, configuration

I have custom configuration fields (added from **system.xml** file in my module) in `Shipping Methods` section in the admin panel:

`System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods` page.

It's not a new shipping method, just few fields to work with the default Table Rates method.

Is there a way to catch when this data is saved/changed? Or where can I dispatch a custom event to catch it? Simply I have to check if my custom fields are changed and to perform some updates with the new values.

**Answer:** 
In my case the event was `admin_system_config_changed_section_carriers`. I've found it in `Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController::saveAction`.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent("admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section}",
    array('website' => $website, 'store' => $store)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this event before to capture the post data and do something with it: **admin_system_config_changed_section_[yoursection]**

```
public function exampleObserver($observer) {

    $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Actually I found the answer few minutes after submitting the question. You're right, this is the event. In my case it was `admin_system_config_changed_section_carriers`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using **admin_system_config_changed_section_[yoursection]** might be too late if you want to get the old value to compare it with the new one or what ever you wonna do.

You could try this event:
**model_config_data_save_before**

Comment: after save, the value is updated, so even in save_after the value is already gone. So you are right. To check whether the old and new value is the same, you have at least to save the value in save_before, if you can not do EVERYTHING in save before.