# Detect change in system.xml field with observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, system.xml

I need to config a observer to detect when a option created in system.xml change its value.

The field is made by the code above:

```
<config>
    <sections>
         <dev>
            <groups>
                <pico_group>
                    <label>SGPico Configurações</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>250</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <ativo translate="label">
                            <label>Pico está Ativo?</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </ativo>
                    </fields>
                </pico_group>
            </groups>
        </dev>
    </sections>
</config>
```

I search and tried to config the observer like that:

```
<admin_system_config_changed_section_dev_pico_group>
    <observers>
        <auto_invoice_order>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>IsabelaFlores_SGPico_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>teste</method>
        </auto_invoice_order>
    </observers>
</admin_system_config_changed_section_dev_pico_group>
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right name of the event is

> admin_system_config_changed_section_**yoursectionname**

group name **pico_group** is not necessary in your event observer configuration.

```
<admin_system_config_changed_section_dev> 
    <observers> 
        <auto_invoice_order> 
            <type>singleton</type> 
            <class>IsabelaFlores_SGPico_Model_Observer</class> 
            <method>teste</method> 
        </auto_invoice_order> 
    </observers> 
</admin_system_config_changed_section_dev>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I change the name and it is working now

Comment: @NatháliaPissuti não tem problema, am glad it helps. As an additional information, this event has been fired from the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php inside the method saveAction // website and store codes can be used in event implementation, so set them as well
            Mage::dispatchEvent("admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section}",
                array('website' => $website, 'store' => $store)
            );

Comment: Aslo check these answers for other alternate events that you can observe  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125336/695 https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/40854/695